# After upgrade to wordpress 5.1.1, select2.js library have big change

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

one of my plugin using select2.js.

After upgraded to Wordpress 5.1.1,  this plugin won't be able to use.
Check the picture below:

https://i.ibb.co/FY74bfr/before-after.jpg

It should show the input box when clicking the select.

I checked how Html shows different, Try to manually html code to see it works but failed.

the code different shows below:

https://i.ibb.co/qYRQ2qZ/different.jpg

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#pf_relation_group").select2({
            placeholder: "Select data group",
            allowClear: true,
            ajax: {
                url: ajaxurl,
                delay: 200,
                method: 'GET',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        action: 'pf-get-data-groups',
                        query: params.term,
                        product_id: $("#post_ID").val()
                    }
                },
                processResults: function (groups, params) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(groups, function (group) {
                            return {
                                text: group.name,
                                slug: group.name,
                                id: group.id
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    $("#pf_relation_vehicle").select2({
        placeholder: "Select vehicles",
        allowClear: true,
        ajax: {
            url: ajaxurl,
            delay: 200,
            method: 'GET',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    action: 'pf-get-vehicles',
                    query: params.term,
                    product_id: $("#post_ID").val()
                }
            },
            processResults: function (vehicles, params) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(vehicles, function (vehicle) {
                        if (parseInt(vehicle.year) === 0) {
                            vehicle.year = '';
                        }
                        const text = (vehicle.mark + ' ' + vehicle.model + ' ' + vehicle.year).trim();
                        return {
                            text: text,
                            slug: text,
                            id: vehicle.id
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

After upgrade to WordPress 5.1.1, I think the library of select2.js should be changed a lot, that's why old function doesn't work.

Comment: I'm fairly sure WordPress itself doesn't supply select2, nor has it changed jQuery version. (There was a security patch to WordPress's jQuery in 5.2.1, but not 5.1.1.) What did you upgrade from? Are there any errors in your browser console which might explain why select2 didn't initialize correctly?

Comment: there's no error in my browser console, the select2 works with another admin page, but not working in the product page, I will try to upgrade to 5.2.2 to see if the function will work so, thanks for reply.